# continuity on the given interval

Tags: limits, continuity

If a function is continuous on $[a,b]$ then it's continous on all points of $(a,b)$. But is vice-versa true.if not then how to do the following problem .Discuss the continuity of $x-|x-x^2|$.without using graphs on the interval $[-1,1]$ . I did it by using limits at $0^{+},0^{-}$ but is it the right way or there is some other way.

Comment: Of course there are other ways, but your way is correct and easy to do.

Comment: So by that you mean vice versa is also true right?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of a function being continuous on an intervall. One thing: you first write $[a,b]$ and then $(a,b)$. While it is true that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then it is continuous in every $x\in (a,b)$, this doesn't hold the other way around. You need $f$ to be continuous in every $x\in[a,b]$ for $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Okay thanks for the comment